# How can I make this image gallery responsive for mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my photo gallery fit within a mobile window. Most of my experience with responsiveness/mobile comes from twitter bootstrap, which does everything for you.

Here is the jsfiddle (buttons don't work since I didn't include my javascript): http://jsfiddle.net/L9hued7b/2/

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="prev">
            <a href="#" class="images">&uArr; </a>
            <a href="#" class="thumbs">&uArr; </a>
        </div>
        <div id="images">
            <!-- large images on left-->
        </div>
        <div id="thumbs">
        <!--thumbnails on right-->  
        </div>
        <div id="next">
            <a href="#" class="images">&dArr; </a>
            <a href="#" class="thumbs">&dArr; </a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

css:

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 600px;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}


#wrapper {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 750px;
        height: 350px;
        padding: 50px 25px 50px 50px;
        margin: -225px 0 0 -412px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            }
#wrapper img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#images, #thumbs {
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#images {
    width: 350px;
}
#thumbs {
    width: 375px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
#thumbs img {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 14px;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#thumbs img.selected, #thumbs img:hover {
    border-color: #333;
}

#thumbs div {
    width: 375px;
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
}
#prev a, #next a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #999;
    position: absolute;
}
#prev a:hover, #next a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#prev a.disabled, #next a.disabled {
    display: none !important;
}
#prev a {
    top: 15px;
}
#next a {
    bottom: 15px;
}
a.images {
    left: 220px;
}
a.thumbs {
    right: 220px;
}

#source {
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
}
#source, #source a {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your css file and you resize the browser you will see they will stack under each other. So when the width of the screen is lower then 500px the boxes will be styled differently. You might need to look at how you position the buttons but you can do that in the @media block so it only applies on screens with a width of lower then 500px.

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {

    #images, #thumbs {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this and fix you issue by your self

```css
/*  #Mobile (Portrait) 
================================================== */
    
/* Note: Design for a width of 320px */
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #wrapper { width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
     #images, #thumbs {display: block;width: 100%;float: left;}
}
/* #Mobile (Landscape)
================================================== */

/* Note: Design for a width of 480px */
    
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
     #wrapper { width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
     #images, #thumbs {display: block;width: 100%;float: left;}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 min-height: 600px;
}
body * {
 font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #333;
 line-height: 22px;
}
#wrapper {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 750px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 50px 25px 50px 50px;
 margin: -225px 0 0 -412px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#wrapper img {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
#images, #thumbs {
 height: 350px;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#images {
 width: 350px;
}
#thumbs {
 width: 375px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}
#thumbs img {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 14px;
 margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#thumbs img.selected, #thumbs img:hover {
 border-color: #333;
}
#thumbs div {
 width: 375px;
 height: 350px;
 float: left;
}
#prev a, #next a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #999;
 position: absolute;
}
#prev a:hover, #next a:hover {
 color: #000;
}
#prev a.disabled, #next a.disabled {
 display: none !important;
}
#prev a {
 top: 15px;
}
#next a {
 bottom: 15px;
}
a.images {
 left: 220px;
}
a.thumbs {
 right: 220px;
}
#source {
 text-align: center;
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 left: 50%;
}
#source, #source a {
 color: #999;
 font-size: 12px;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 #wrapper {
 margin:0 !important;
 position:relative !important;
 margin-left:auto !important;
 margin-right:auto !important;
 margin-top:10% !important;
 padding:20px 6px 20px 20px !important;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:50%;
 margin-bottom:10% !important;
 height:765px;
}
 #images {
width: 100%;
margin-top:20px;
}
#thumbs {
width: 100%;
margin-left:0;
margin-top:20px;
}
#thumbs img {
padding: 14px;
margin: 0 22px 25px 0;
}
}
 @media (max-width:600px) {
 #wrapper {
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px !important;
 height: 588px !important;
}
 #images, #thumbs {
height: 284px;
}
 #images img {
 width:auto;
 max-width:100%;
 height:auto;
 max-height:100%;
}
 #thumbs img {
padding: 7px;
margin: 0 0px 20px 20px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
}
 @media (max-width:480px) {
 #wrapper {
padding: 20px 0px 20px 30px !important;
width: 70%;
}
}
@media (max-width:360px) {
 #wrapper {
padding: 20px 0px 20px 30px !important;
width: 70%;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="prev"> <a href="#" class="images">&uArr; </a> <a href="#" class="thumbs">&uArr; </a> </div>
  <div id="images"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> 0 <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="350" height="350" /> </div>
  <div id="thumbs"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"  width="70" height="70" /> </div>
  <div id="next"> <a href="#" class="images">&dArr; </a> <a href="#" class="thumbs">&dArr; </a> </div>
</div>
</body>
```